# Downloading Public Test Realm Client

Tags: diablo-iii

I have a fully updated retail client of Diablo 3 installed. I have downloaded the public test realm (PTR) installer. When I run this installer, it starts to download and indicates it needs 15GB of free hard drive space. Does the PTR installer download the entire game again, or just the latest (PTR) patch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PTR client is completely separate from the standard D3 client, so it will have to be a separate install.  Once you've installed it once, any future PTR patches will be downloaded just the same like the normal servers.

Comment: But does installing the PTR download a DVDs-worth of data? Like downloading 4 or 8GB?

Comment: @sabrewolfy its the same as reinstalling a entirely separate diablo 3 client, so you'll have to basically redownload all of diablo 3

Comment: I recently saw a post describing a way to avoid this large initial PTR download. It involved copying the D3 live client data to the PTR folder and then updating, along with some other steips. If I find the link, I'll post it here.